# AWS App Runner Deploy fails due to failing health checks of my nodejs app image

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, containers

I would like to start off by saying I am pretty new to containerization, and the Amazon services that use them. I am implementing whatever I am learning from educational videos.

I have a NodeJs App [essentially a set of APIs] that I want to deploy. To make the code portable I have dockerized my nodejs image, and also published it to ECR.

However, when I am trying to deploy it using the App runner - the deployment failed, saying the health check failed.

I have looked up similar issues here on SO, and their response was deleting the current app running service and creating a new one, which doesn't work for me.

I figured the culprit might be:

- using the App Runner GUI, the health check configuration is preset to TCP protocol, when my app uses http.
- to be able to custom configure my health check object, I used the AWS CLI, but I am still facing the same issue.
- Additionally, I also added a health check endpoint to my app at `/` path that returns 200 status and an ok flag.

The error says:
`health check failed on port 8080. make sure you have configured the port number correctly`

Now, my port is configured at 8080 only.

Steps that weere succesful:

- building the docker image
- pushing the docker image to ECR

Additionally, I am pasting my appRunner.json configuration file for more clarity and I will also post my docker file:

- appRunner config json file:

```json
{
    "ServiceName": "micro_server",
    "SourceConfiguration": {
        "AuthenticationConfiguration": { 
         "AccessRoleArn": "<my ARN_ I didnt post the actula string here>"
      },
        "AutoDeploymentsEnabled": true,
        "ImageRepository": {
            "ImageIdentifier": "397552631910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mico_server:latest",
            "ImageRepositoryType": "ECR"
        }
    },
    "HealthCheckConfiguration": {
        "HealthyThreshold": 5,
        "Interval": 10,
        "Path": "/",
        "Protocol": "HTTP",
        "UnhealthyThreshold": 5
    },
    "InstanceConfiguration": {
        "Cpu": "1 vCPU",
        "Memory": "3 GB"
    }
}
```

- dockerfile

```docker
FROM node:gallium-alpine3.14
WORKDIR / 
ENV NODE_ENV=dev

COPY / .
RUN npm install

CMD npm run serve
EXPOSE 8080
```

- this is how my index.js looks like

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fs = require('fs')

const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerSpec = require('./swaggerConfig');
const connectToDatabase = require('./db');

require('dotenv').config()


const app = express();
// url encoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/Images'))

app.use('/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));

// health check EP for http protocol
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ok:true})
})

fs.readdirSync('./routes').map(route => {
  app.use(`/api/${route.split('.')[0]}`, require('./routes/' + route))
})


// BASE_URL/API
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
  // console.log(process.env)


});
```

*Dealing w Docker*
I am on a linux machine - garuda.

- to run my docker image, I use the `--network='host'` flag to run my app and also be able to connect to it at localhost:PORT
- If I run it without the `--network='host'` flag, the app still runs on 8080, but I can't access it on localhost:8080.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but -- we had countless issues using AppRunner with a Docker container. We switched to using the "app from github codebase" option, and no problems. In general I've found this to be a good idea for orgs that don't have large, dedicated devops teams: let AWS (or whatever cloud provider) handle as much of the complexity as possible. In this case, just telling AWS "here's our code, create an app from it" instead of trying to create and maintain a container.